# Как убрать восклицательные знаки с файлов (папок) в Netbeans 8.2?

Tags: ide, netbeans

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Интересует как убрать с отдельного проекта (папки) в Netbeans, а если это невозможно, то вообще отключить красные восклицательные знаки на папках (файлах) в Netbeans?

Comment: На полях можно ткнуть по любой ошибке и выбрать "фильтровать ошибки ... "

Comment: а в этом случае фильтрация ошибок будет применена только к конкретному проекту или вообще к любым проектам в netbeans?

Comment: только к этому проекту

Comment: спасибо огромное, вроде разобрался!